# codigo angular js de filtro no me funciona

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
    $scope.items = [
        {id:71610067, name:'John'},
        {id:2, name:'Steve'},
        {id:3, name:'Joey'},
        {id:4, name:'Mary'},
        {id:5, name:'Marylin'}];
    
    $scope.items2 = $scope.items;
    
    $scope.$watch('search', function(val)
    { 
        $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, val);
    });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="data.js" ></script>
<body>

<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>



<p>The list will only consists of names matching the filter.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Alguien me ayuda a saber porque mi codigo no funciona?

Comment: Te estaría faltando crear un `angular.module` y registrar el `controller` en el mismo. Te recomiendo que leas la [guia para desarrolladores](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/guide/controller) de `Angular`

Answer (score 3):

Yo lo haria mas sencillo sin hacer el filtro en el controller

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="query">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{item.name:query}">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```